# Cleanup TestManagement Database - ExtensionNotFound

Tags: tfs

After upgrading from TFS 2017 RTM to TFS 2017 Update 3, the following job started to throw ExtensionNotFound exception.

On the hub that shows the Service Hooks there aren't any available, nor any credentials are being required to open it.

Is there any reason for such behavior in the TFS 2017 Update3? Maybe some special permissions are required for the account being used, it that Update?

Possibly another note on that behavior is that there are some errors in the EventViewer, around the same time as the mentioned jobs fails in TFS 2017 Update3:

> The subscriber
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Server.TestRunEventListener
>   has been disabled.
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Server, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type
>   FileNotFoundException)

I do have the assembly so I am not sure what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

After looking deeper into that behavior I have been able to answer part of the question, about the missing assembly. Actually where is it installed currently, it does not have all of the dependencies for real. It is in the

> Application Tier\TFSJobAgent folder

And there part of the assemblies which it needs are not there. So I have moved it to the proper location (I believe) that is should be both:

> Application Tier\Web Services\bin
>
> Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Plugins

Instead, because there are all of the needed assemblies that

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Server

is referencing. I have also installed on another machine TFS 2017 RTM, and this proves that the current location is wrong of that particular assembly.

Now it is still interesting why that had happened, and if there are other issues with moving that assemblies around, and why it has been moved at first place after the upgrade to TFS Update 3?

I would need some time to verify the initial question about ExtentionNotFound though, will keep you updated.